# python: print few keys value

Tags: python, python-3.x

From below output i need only name,policy to be printed

```
{'response': {'backupResponseList': [{'id': '20',
                                      'mounted': False,
                                      'name': 'snapshot_11-29-2019_02.31.01.5708',
                                      'policy': 'SCV_DLY_NoDR',
                                      'startTime': 1574991087454,
                                      'status': 'Completed',
                                      'vmwareSnapshot': 'Yes'}]},
 'statusCode': 200,
 'statusMessage': 'OK'}
```

Comment: is this json file?

Comment: yes..it's a json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data = {'response': {'backupResponseList': [{'id': '20',
                                  'mounted': False,
                                  'name': 'snapshot_11-29-2019_02.31.01.5708',
                                  'policy': 'SCV_DLY_NoDR',
                                  'startTime': 1574991087454,
                                  'status': 'Completed',
                                  'vmwareSnapshot': 'Yes'}]},
'statusCode': 200,
'statusMessage': 'OK'}

data2 = data['response']['backupResponseList'][0]
print(data2['name'])
print(data2['policy'])
```

**Output**

```
>> snapshot_11-29-2019_02.31.01.5708
>> SCV_DLY_NoDR
```

Comment: Just update my answer because there is only object in the list you can use this as i did. because loop decreases the efficiency.